# Simple php file call, do I need to do a CORS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

Do I need to make a CORS request If I'm just making a file php call on the same server?

Example:

```
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: './php/file.php',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error!"); 
  }
});
```

Edit: Thanks @Amit Soni, changed failure to error.

Comment: `error` instead of `failure`

Comment: quick answer, no you don't

Comment: if `php` folder is in same `directory`, use `url: 'php/file.php'`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the path of your endpoint which is the same origin? `CORS` is only required when making requests to a different or outside of domain

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and here's an [example](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm) of the implementation if required.

How this helps.